# Invalid argument passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the [surface_perception package](http://wiki.ros.org/surface_perception) to get some table top data but I've been getting this error message

```
Invalid argument passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
```

after running the surface segmentation for the multiple times and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

The error message appears when i launch this file:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find rosbridge_server)/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch" />
  <node pkg="tf2_web_republisher" type="tf2_web_republisher" name="tf2_web_republisher" launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"/>
</launch>
```

i tried adding the launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args" to the tf2_web_republisher node but it just shows up the same error messages without indicating where its occuring.

An odd thing that happens is that the visualisation shows one of the axes to be enlarged as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/nVas9R2)

I know this is related to some empty frame_ids but i cant seem to figure out where they are. When I run

```
rostopic echo /tf2_web_republisher/result
```

then all frame ids are empty even when there's no error message.

any advice would be highly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299453/invalid-argument-passed-to-lookuptransform-argument-source_frame-in-tf2-frame_ids-cannot-be-empty/) by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the node in question [is only doing one lookup](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/tf2_web_republisher/blob/cd851b02dae791654b222eee06478c2deed0d3ae/src/tf_web_republisher.cpp#L306). You can download the source and print out whatever information you want. The exception is being caught, so I don't think `gdb` is going to help you here. I'd remove that.

If you can't find any empty frames, try doing a `rostopic echo /tf` or a `rostopic echo /tf_static` to see if any of the raw `tf` data shows empty frames. You could `grep` for an empty `frame_id` or `child_frame_id` field. Then you can backtrack to whatever node is publishing the transform in question.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-08-03**:
i tried doing a grep for empty frame_id for both /tf and /tf_static but didnt get anything. Will try to download the source and print out some info

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-08-03**:
so I included an extra if statement to make sure it doesnt try to lookup the transform if the source or target frames are empty. how do i find out what the exact cause is though? TFPair does not seem to have any identifiers. Also I'm still getting the enlarged axis arrow as mentioned in my post